# Editor that can open directory on MacOS / Linux

Tags: osx, editors, sublime-text

Is there a default editor (vi or nano don't seem to cut it) that can open a directory and view files on MacOS or Linux?

I have Sublime Text installed, but for machines w/o sublime text, what might be the best alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> vi or nano don't seem to cut it

VIM and NeoVIM both do.  Run `vim .` or `nvim .` and see.

On that score: `vi` should on Linux operating systems, since generally VIM takes the place of `vi` there (albeit that this is configurable via things like Debian's "alternatives" mechanism).  `vi` lacks this functionality on other systems where it is, rather, another different vi clone without this, such as nvi.

Comment: is there some graphical tool  that is easier to use than vim? that comes default on most *nix systems? I guess not

Comment: People already want to close your question for being unspecific and opinion-based.  "easier to use" is a matter of opinion, and "some graphical tool" is even less specific than "default editor" which is what you actually asked and what is answered.

Comment: wel vim doesnt seem to come out of the box on Ubuntu, only vi, so we all fucked by the universe right now

Comment: You should read the answer again, in particular the part about the "alternatives" mechanism and how `vi` is just a pointer to the actual program, which is generally VIM.

Comment: well since you answer is prob accurate i bestow upon you the green check of goodness

Answer (score 0):

Most Mac editors allow you to do what you want. I use the Atom editor a lot. TextEdit, which comes on Macs will do it as well. Along with many others.